# EOFException in readUTF

Tags: java, eofexception

I am getting below `EOFException` while using `readUTF()` method, please let me know how could i overcome with this problem and also please suggest how `readUTF()` transfers socket information over the other networks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GreetingServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String servername =args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try {
            System.out.println("Server Name "+ servername +"Port"+port);

            Socket client = new Socket(servername,port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to"+ client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outs = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(outs);
            dout.writeUTF("Hello From"+client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
            System.out.println("Server Says"+ din.readUTF());
            client.close();
        }
        catch (EOFException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your server side code. The problem should be on server side which is sending incorrect/incomplete data

Answer (score 8):

You have reached the end of the stream. There is no more data to read.

Possibly your server isn't using `writeUTF(),` or you are out of sync with it. If the server is writing lines you should be using `BufferedReader.readLine().`

Comment: if it is not written using writeUTF then how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @AlexanderZaldostanov Err, don't call `readUTF()`? If it isn't written with `writeUTF()` you shouldn't be callling `readUTF()`. You should call something else, depending on how it was written.

Comment: ... also the readUTF() and writeUTF() should be in the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) for `readUtf()` state;

> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit
>   integer in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This
>   integer value is called the UTF length and specifies the number of
>   additional bytes to be read. These bytes are then converted to
>   characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is
>   computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte
>   following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.

This suggests to me that what your trying to read with readUtf() isn't UTF, as the `EOFException` occurs when the [End of File (EOF) is read unexpectedly.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html)

Check that you are reading the right types in the same order that your server is sending them etc. You should be following a decided protocol, rather than blindly reading.

Comment: The EOFException also occurs *at EOF* of course, when it is encountered 'expectedly'.